# SELECT filtrando os primeiros resultados

Tags: php, sql

tenho o campo DESTACAR  (sim) (nao)
Gostaria de Exibir os resultados retirando os 4 primeiros resultados DESTACAR (sim) e exibir o restante dos registros tanto os (sim) a partir do 4º quanto os (nao)

ja tentei usar `LIMIT` `OFFSET` mais nao funcionou

```
SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE status='Publicado' ORDER BY idnoticia DESC LIMIT 6,4
```

alguma alternativa?

Comment: Poste o que tentou e não funcionou. `LIMIT OFFSET` é o mais apropriado. Qual banco esta utilizando? Adicione também um exemplo, para ficar mais claro.

Comment: Você está usando mySql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a seguinte `subconsulta`:

```
SELECT *
FROM noticias n
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id
    FROM noticias
    WHERE destacar = 'Sim'
    ORDER BY id LIMIT 4
  ) p);
```

Exemplo funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7db7c2/21/0).

Comment: nesse caso se eu tivesse 100 noticias 50 sim e 50 nao as NAO nem apareceriam nos resultados

Comment: Editei a resposta, veja se é isso @ArsomNolasco

Comment: Se não for MYSQL pode utilizar o TOP 4 na subconsulta, se não estou enganado

Comment: funcionou, porem tentei colocar um limit no final so que deu erro ...  ORDER BY id LIMIT 4 ) p) ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 6; ... sabe pq o erro?

Comment: Você precisa informar o campo após o comando `ORDER BY`, ficaria assim: `... ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6` @ArsomNolasco

Answer (score 2):

Use a operação `UNION` para unir o resultado de duas consultas diferentes em uma só.

A consulta antes do `UNION` teria apenas os resultados destacados, enquanto que a consulta após seria complementada com os resultados não-destacados.

```
SELECT *
FROM noticias
WHERE status='Publicado'
AND destacar='sim'
ORDER BY idnoticia DESC LIMIT 4
UNION
SELECT *
FROM noticias
WHERE status='Publicado'
AND destacar='nao'
ORDER BY idnoticia DESC
```

Daí em diante basta implementar uma paginação à sua maneira, usando `LIMIT` e `OFFSET`.

Comment: Mas nesse caso a 2ª query não vai exibir os `destacar='sim'` que estiverem abaixo da quarta posição, não é? Não seria o caso da 2ª query exibir todos registros menos os ID'S que forem listados na 1ª query?

Comment: @PapaCharlie pelo que eu entendi as linhas da tabela possuem 'sim' ou nao' na coluna, o que significa que não haveria repetição entre os resultados de ambas as consultas. Depende um pouco da estrutura da tabela também.

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi ele queria subir os 4 `sim` e manter o resto em ordem. Foi só a interpretação :)

Comment: mais no caso a segunda consulta teria que pegar os outros destacar=sim -os 4 primeiros juntamente com os destacar=nao. Resumidamente seria uma consulta geral retirando os 4 primeiros ID com destacar sim

Comment: Então, essa consulta lista todos o `sim` menos os 4 primeiros, e faz uma união com a consulta que retorna todos os `não`, só não sei dizer qual é mais performatica, se essa com union ou a anterior com subconsulta.

Answer (score 1):

Pra fazer isso é mais fácil programando.
Faça uma select normal com os items que você quer e depois verifique se o campo é sim e remova

```
resultados = query(Select....

Contador = 0
Para Cada resultado Em resultados
{
    Se resultado.destaque == sim E Contador < 4 {
        remova resultado de resultados;
        Contador++
    }
}
```

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE ORDER BY idnoticia DESC LIMIT 3 "; $stmt->execute();
$exibe = stmt->fetchAll();foreach ($exibe as $u) {if $exibe.destacar == Destacado AND $Contador < 4 { Qual a funcao de remover resultado ?? $Contador++ }} echo